# Question related to Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a coin with probability of coming up heads in a throw be $p$. Therefore the probability of two heads when tossing two coins will be $p^2$, similarly while tossing 3 coins the probability of three heads will be $p^3$. Hence we get a sequence that while tossing $n$ coins probability of $n$ heads will be $p^n$. Can we generate an event using the above knowledge that its occurring probability will be $p^{1/2}$?

Comment: If $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational and in many other cases then you need a potentially unlimited number of throws.

Comment: I think it is not possible to put a limit on the number of throws needed for $p=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\sqrt{p}=\frac{1}{2}$, and I suspect it is not possible for any rational $p$ with $0\lt p \lt 1$